# MySQL - LIKE not working with CONCAT and UNION

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I cannot figure out why the `LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause is not working...

```sql
set @tenantId = 1;

select
    id,
    type,
    name,
    url,
    searchBy
from (
    select 
        tenantId, 
        'Производ' type, 
        id, 
        concat(uid, ' - ', name) name, 
        concat(uid, ' ', name) searchBy, 
        concat('/master/items/', id) url 
    from master_item
    where tenantId = @tenantId

    union all

    select 
        tenantId, 
        'Компанија' type, 
        id, 
        concat(uid, ' - ', name) name, 
        concat(uid, ' ', name) searchBy, 
        concat('/master/subjects/', id) url 
    from master_subject
    where tenantId = @tenantId
) t1

where searchBy like '%Пром%' -- DOES NOT WORK
```

**The queries below work!**

```sql
-- query above
where searchBy like '%0001%' -- Seems like it detects numbers, but not characters?
```

```sql
select *
from master_subject
where name like '%Пром%' -- Why does this work, and searchBy doesn't?
```

**EDIT:**

What I noticed was that the `UNION ALL` somehow breaks it, as the query below works...

```sql
set @tenantId = 1;

select
    id,
    type,
    name,
    url,
    searchBy
from (
    select 
        tenantId, 
        'Компанија' type, 
        id, 
        concat(uid, ' - ', name) name, 
        concat(uid, ' ', name) searchBy, 
        concat('/master/subjects/', id) url 
    from master_subject
    where tenantId = @tenantId
) t1

where searchBy like '%Пром%' -- DOES NOT WORK
```

Comment: Perhaps because `Пром` and `Прои` are not the same?

Comment: @ChrisMaurer Huh? Where did you see `Прои`?

Comment: type `Производ`

Comment: type, not tenantID,  so maybe not...

Comment: @Ivan please try this `select *
from master_subject
where tenantId = 1 AND name like '%Пром%'`
Is that return rows?

Comment: @ChrisMaurer I apologize. I don't understand what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: Hmm, I see no difference https://dbfiddle.uk/tP9Qdu08

Comment: @User12345 Thanks for the fiddle. What I noticed is that when I remove the union all and leave one one of the subqueries, it does work... Somehow the union all breaks it... I edited my post.

Comment: `UNION ALL` should have nothing to do with the error. Maybe there are some data that breaks the subquery. Please share your table's data type

Comment: @User12345 This is weird... The fiddle works. https://dbfiddle.uk/XjpB0ERQ

Comment: which version do you use on your side?

Comment: @User12345 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2

Comment: `searchBy`  is composite field and no real column there. So, it's not worked @PonmaniChinnaswamy

Comment: @Ivan I checked you missed ` where tenantId = @tenantId`. But, even I add this. it still works

Comment: @User12345 The `@tenantId` does not change things. The only thing I noticed is the `UNION ALL` and I have no idea why it works in the fiddle, and not on my machine...

Answer (score 0):

This happened on version `8.0.32`.

After upgrading to `8.0.36` the problem went away.